# Apply changes to docker container after 'exec' into it

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have successfully shelled into a RUNNING docker container using

docker exec -i -t 7be21f1544a5 bash

I have made some changes to some json files and wanted to apply these changes to reflect online.

I am a beginner and have tried to restart, mount in vain. What strings I have to replace when I mount using docker run?

Is there any online sample?

```
CONTAINER ID: 7be21f1544a5
IMAGE: gater/web
COMMAND: "/bin/sh -c 'nginx'"
CREATED: 4 weeks ago
STATUS: Up 44 minutes
PORTS: 443/tcp, 172.16.0.1:10010->80/tcp
NAMES: web
```

Answer (score 5):

You can run either create a Dockefile and run:

```
docker build .
```

from the same directory where your `Dockerfile` is located.

or you can run:

```
docker run -i -t <docker-image> bash
```

or (if your container is already running)

```
docker exec -i -t <container-id> bash
```

once you are in the shell make all the changes you please. Then run:

```
docker commit <container-id> myimage:0.1
```

You will have a new docker image locally `myimage:0.1`. If you want to push to a docker repository (dockerhub or your private docker repo) you can run:

```
docker push myimage:0.1
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I made the change while I am in bash to a running container. but it doesn't reflect the changes online.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do it :

- Dockerfile approach

You need to know what changes you have made into Docker container after you have exec into it and also the Dockerfile of the image .

Lets say you installed additional rpm using yum install command after entering into the container (yum install perl-HTML-Format) and updated some file say /opt/test.json inside contianer (take a backup of this file in Docker host in some directory or in directory Dockerfile exist)

The above command/steps you can place in Dockerfile as

```
RUN  yum install perl-HTML-Format
COPY /docker-host-dir/updated-test.json  /opt/test.json
```

Once you update the Dockerfile, create the new image and push it to Docker repository

```
docker build -t test_image .
docker push test_image:latest
```

You can save the updated Dockerfile for future use.

- Docker commit command approach

After you made the changes to container, use below commands to create a new image from container's changes and push it online

```
docker commit container-id test_image
docker push test_image

docker commit --help  
Usage:  docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I made the change while I am in bash to a running container. but it doesn't reflect the changes online.

Comment: decribe what exact steps you did, how you pushed the changes online ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that. After you figured out what you needed you throw away the running container (`git rm 7be21f1544a5`), repeat the changes in the [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/) and [build](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/build/) a new image to run.

Comment: repeat the changes in the Dockerfile? what is the instructions? I see the follwong: FROM kyma/docker-nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
COPY ./website.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

ADD dist/ /var/www

CMD 'nginx'

Comment: Yeah you should rebuild your Dockerfile, but sometimes you do need to hotfix a running container and at commit the image to at least have a reference of what has been done. It is true that such image may have other unexpected changes and shouldn't be used to start a new container, but I think it's reasonable in some scenarios. Besides, production environments are not the only environments where Docker is useful.